# Pesky Google acting up

Tags: google-chrome, google, google-calendar

Google installed something called

```
GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent
```

That will run endlessly in background every hour, consuming resources and battery life.

Here is a snippet from Console-system log.

```
Aug 16 03:40:58 myMBA GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[18523]: 2017-08-16 03:40:58.581 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[18523/0x7fffe42623c0] [lvl=2] -[KSAgentApp(PrivateMethods) setupLoggerOutput] Agent default/global settings: <KSAgentSettings:0x100420620 bundleID=com.google.Keystone.Agent lastCheck=2017-08-16 05:11:24 +0000 lastServerCheck=2017-08-16 05:11:22 +0000 lastCheckStart=2017-08-16 00:35:06 +0000 checkInterval=604800.000000 uiDisplayInterval=604800.000000 sleepInterval=60480.000000 jitterInterval=900 maxRunInterval=0.000000 isConsoleUser=1 ticketStorePath=/Users/xxxyyy/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore runMode=3 daemonUpdateEngineBrokerServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine daemonAdministrationServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration logEverything=0 logBufferSize=2048 alwaysPromptForUpdates=0 productIDToUpdate=(null) lastUIDisplayed=2016-09-03 01:32:53 +0000 alwaysShowStatusItem=0 updateCheckTag=(null) printResults=NO userInitiated=NO>

Aug 16 04:41:21 myMBA GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[18567]: 2017-08-16 04:41:21.560 GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent[18567/0x7fffe42623c0] [lvl=2] -[KSAgentApp(PrivateMethods) setupLoggerOutput] Agent default/global settings: <KSAgentSettings:0x100332590 bundleID=com.google.Keystone.Agent lastCheck=2017-08-16 05:11:24 +0000 lastServerCheck=2017-08-16 05:11:22 +0000 lastCheckStart=2017-08-16 00:35:06 +0000 checkInterval=604800.000000 uiDisplayInterval=604800.000000 sleepInterval=60480.000000 jitterInterval=900 maxRunInterval=0.000000 isConsoleUser=1 ticketStorePath=/Users/xxxyyy/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/TicketStore/Keystone.ticketstore runMode=3 daemonUpdateEngineBrokerServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine daemonAdministrationServiceName=com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration logEverything=0 logBufferSize=2048 alwaysPromptForUpdates=0 productIDToUpdate=(null) lastUIDisplayed=2016-09-03 01:32:53 +0000 alwaysShowStatusItem=0 updateCheckTag=(null) printResults=NO userInitiated=NO>
```

It is seemingly trying to update Google software on my Mac.
I have changed its check interval from 18000 (5 hr) to 604800 (once per week) with

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 604800
```

but it is ignoring that.

Macbook Air 2012 with Sierra.

How do I fix it, or kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm by no means qualified to fix Google problems, I ended up using brute force.

First I renamed this folder :
/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/

Then I killed the GoogleSoftwareUpdate update Program with

```
sudo launchctl remove com.google.keystone.system.agent
```

First result is in: (Victory)

```
Aug 16 20:51:06 myMBA com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.keystone.system.agent[771]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent
```

We will see tomorrow if it stays put over night and stops trying to update Google Software every hour.